# Is my method of accessing a class from different classes right? (Android studio, Java)

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to access an instance of a class from a few other classes. The class i want to access should hold settings that the user has chosen.

In my MainActivity i create an instance of the class that should be accessible through other classes.

```
  public static SettingsHolder holder = new SettingsHolder();
```

Then, i start another activity from the MainActivity:

```
public void onSettings(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Which opens up the class Settings. In the onCreate method of Settings i have:

```
private SettingsHolder holder;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    holder = MainActivity.holder;
}
```

From the Settings class above i should now be able to set and get public variables/methods from the holder class, right? The reason i ask is because when i searched how to do this i only found methods that suggested using something like `putExtras` and `getExtras` in my `onSettings` method.

Comment: Can you provide a reason why you are defining your own SettingsHolder class instead of using the libraries' functionalities? E.g. I think you should look into using `SharedPreferences` for example.

Comment: I havent gotten there yet, in the SettingsHolder class i will call a method that sets all the variables in that class using sharedpreferences. But you are saying i dont need to create a new instance of the SettingsHolder class at all, how would i do this?

Comment: Just use the `SharedPreferences` class directly. It is provided by the Android library. Why do you use a class that does the same thing at the end. I don't see a reason for that. Read the Android documentation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work another way to do it is to have the `SettingsHolder`  class have a static reference to itself.

So in `SettingsHolder` have:

```
public class SettingsHolder{

   public static SettingsHolder instance;

   public SettingsHolder{

       if(instance == null)
           instance = this; 
   }
```

Using this you can reference it anywhere using `SettingsHolder.instance` after it has been initialized without have to worry about passing around references.

Comment: This works very well, and I think it is called a Singleton (pattern).